# Troubles with aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm testing my app on 320X480 phone and everything looks fine, but here's a screen from user's HTC ONE X, and it looks really bad. It should look just like that but over the entire screen.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc4sjq6e1yo3xkv/Screenshot_2013-05-11-12-11-08.png

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKviz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Kviz opšte kulture!"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bStart"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bTopScores"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="Tabela"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPodesavanja"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:text="Podešavanja"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bPravila"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:text="Pravila"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bKontakt"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:text="Kontakt"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />

                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/bIzlaz"
                     android:layout_width="170dp"
                     android:layout_height="48dp"
                     android:padding="0dp"
                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                     android:text="Izlaz"
                     android:textSize="26sp" />

                 <com.google.ads.AdView
                     android:id="@+id/adViewMenu"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:adUnitId="a1518a6ce0420ab"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Test with applying fill_parent to height and width of main linear layout.

Comment: Tried, it's the same.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried with gravity or layout_gravity = center to main linear layout ?

Comment: No, but I will try right now.

Comment: I've tried it. layout_gravity does nothing and gravity just place it in the middle, does not stratch it. For example that ad on the bottom still has space on each side.

Comment: how it looks.is it shows only half screen?

Comment: Now, with these changes? It looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/jYTEamg.jpg). But on acctual device it looks even worse, smaller.

Comment: Ohkk. So now you have to move your ad layout to bottom right ?

Comment: It's not only ad the problem. It's the whole thing. I will post a screen as soon I get one from user, cause it's 720X1280 HDPI screen and I don't have that option in Eclipse emulator, only Xhdpi. Otherwise, I would try it myself in emulator.

Comment: Are you sure it is 720 HDPI and not XHDPI? The device doesn't look like a small tablet. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&hl=pl

Comment: [Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hsn8ab82rdo7tt1/Screenshot_2013-05-11-13-15-03.png) what he sent me. It's Htc One X.

Comment: Does he have a custom ROM that could be misconfigured as HDPI instead of XHDPI?

Comment: No, it's a stock rom.

Comment: Interesting. Can you ask him to install ScreenInfo app I posted a link to few comments ago, make a screenshot and share?

Comment: [Here is the screen](http://i.imgur.com/RTM6K7P.png). And the [second one](http://i.imgur.com/RTM6K7P.png).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample of layout. Using weights to determine sizes should help you achieve what you want. If you don't have different images for different screen sizes using weighs may help.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/btn_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <!-- put you buttons in here, and use weights for balancing the menu -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this helps. I know this is not the best way, but for a simple layout like the one you need it should do the job.